# Select common Interactions mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this 3 tables:

```
[user]
id | name  |  level
10 | John  |   1
11 | Josh  |   2
12 | Mary  |   3
```

```
[level_interaction]
level | interact_with
  1   |     1
  1   |     2

  2   |     1
  2   |     2
  2   |     3

  3   |     2
  3   |     3
```

```
room_id | user_id
1       |  10
1       |  11

2       |  11
2       |  12

3       | 11
```

what I want is select which level can interact with the room.

- If I check for **room 1**, the answer should be **level 1 and 2** (because John is level 1 and he is only able to interact with level 2) even though Josh as level 2 can interact with level 3.
- If I check for **room 3**, because only Josh is there, the answer should be **1 2 and 3**.
- If I select the **room 2**, the answer should be level **2 and 3**.

Basically what I want is a way to select common interaction level for members on the room!

Check the table/dataset on: https://paiza.io/projects/NKkAQUg9CuB_46rXZdEVEA?language=mysql

Comment: If you start with room 1, then level 3 should be included since Josh can interact with level 3, but you say it shouldn't. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi @TheImaler 
on the Room 1, if Mary(level 3) joins, John would not be able to interact with her. 
Basically everyone in the room should be able to interact with each other. 
does it make sense? thanks

Comment: The table/dataset you added to the question defers structurally quite a bit from the explanation here.

Comment: It should be updated now, matching exactly the same names on the question. thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and `group by li.interact_with` with a condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select li.interact_with
from room r
inner join user u on u.id = r.user_id
inner join level_interaction li on li.level = u.level
where r.room_id = 1
group by li.interact_with
having count(*) = (select count(user_id) from room where room_id = 1);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f025dbecc1162cdfe95e5c3e920d6c80).
Results (for `room_id = 1`):

```
> | interact_with |
> | ------------: |
> |             1 |
> |             2 |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked! 
Now I will try to understand the logic :) 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what version of MySQL you are using so I'll assume it's a modern one. In MySQL 8.x you can use a CTE.

For example:

```
with
x as (
  select u.name, i.interact_with as level
  from room r
  join user u on u.id = r.user_id
  join level_interation i on i.level = u.level
  where r.room_id = 1 -- this is the starting room
)
select level
from x 
group by level
having count(distinct name) = (
  select count(distinct name) from x
)
```

Comment: can you do it on mysql 5? thank you!